# Does the Torah prohibit men from shaking women hands?

Tags: history, women, morality, gender

My friend is devoutly Jewish and when he met my family, he shaked hands with all members of my family, accept for my mother and sister, claiming that both Judaism and the Torah prohibit men from touching or shaking the hands of women, is this true and what Torah verse prohibits this?

(I want to understand the faith more)

Comment: https://dinonline.org/2016/01/18/shaking-hands-with-women/

Comment: hi Connor and thanks for the question. I hope you found a good answer in the links provided. Welcome to MY

Comment: Thank you so much Rabbi Kai